# SSADM for Dummies

Tags: feasibility, system-analysis

this question might look dumb but I need to have a clear idea when learning about something new :)

In SSADM, do we have to do a comprehensive study about the "feasibility" (Stage0)? How can we get an idea about the feasibility before even performing "investigation" (Stage1) about the business?

What is actually expected in Stage0 anyway?

Thanks. Hope someone would shed a light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My references are not available to me at the moment so this is from memory - I think the feasibility stage is about getting the project off the ground - why should people commit resources to even an investigation. So when they are talking about feasibility, and the contents of the report things that are likely to be covered are a broad statement of the problem; why it is a problem; why a system solution looks like the way to go to solve the problem; who will pay for it; who is sponsering it and who will benefit from it.

By definition, it is impossible to do a comprehensive study of feasibility before getting into the work, but rather I think of a feasibility picture as painting a picture of what might be if this project were to go ahead - so broad stroke rather than detailed and comprehensive.

In essence the feasibility stage is answering the questions "why should we bother with this project; and if we are bothered to do this project do we think we are capable of doing it.

Comment: @Sara - sorry when I got back to my boat I found these particular references were a casualty of my move onto the boat - which involved selling/giving away 15,000 books.

Comment: perhaps you can find the info at http://yourdon.com/strucanalysis/wiki/index.php?title=Table_of_Contents